# Is there a shorthand for angular.element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, element

I have just started using AngularJS and I was wondering if there is a shorthand for writing `angular.element`?

Similar to `jQuery` being the same as `$`.

If not, What would be the best way to alias it? Maybe like this globally?

```
var ae = angular.element;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no alias for `angular.element`, but as you said you can create your own the way you did.

Be that as it may, `angular.element` is not used very often, thanks to angular directives, so I'm not sure an alias would be useful.